# Show and hide an element with dynamic IDs on jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several checkboxes on a Wordpress page with an id of the following format

`id = 'more-talktime-{{post.id}}` where the `post.id` is set dynamically.

Then I have a div element with the id of `id = 'talktime-options-{{post.id}}'`

What I try to do is when clicking on the checkbox, it will show/hide the related div element. I tried it with this:

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('[id^=more-talktime-]').change(function(){
            var id = this.id.split('-').pop();
                if(this.checked)
                    jQuery('#talktime-options-' + id).fadeIn('slow');
                else
                    jQuery('#talktime-options-' + id).fadeOut('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

I confirmed that the `var id` is the right one. But the show/hide doesn't work and I don't have any error on the console.

The div element has a `display: none` by default.

Edit to add some HTML code too:

```
<div class="col-md-6 add-on-service">
    <h3>More Talktime</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="more-talktime" id="more-talktime-{{post.id}}" class="add-on-service-checkbox">
    <label for="more-talktime" class="add-on-service-description">blah blah blah</label>
</div>

<div class="add-on-service talktime-options hidden-box" id="talktime-options-{{post-id}}">
    <h3>Choose Talktime Duration</h3>
        ......
</div>
```

**Fixed**
I found the problem. The div element had a typo as you see on the HTML code and instead of {{post.id}} it was {{post-id}} with a dash. Such a silly mistake. But all of your comments and answers helped me dig more on it and find the issue.

Comment: can you add html too?

Comment: What do you get if you add (before `if(this.checked)`) the code: `alert(jQuery('#talktime-options-' + id).length);`

Comment: Are the `#more-talktime-` elements *added* dynamically?  Or are they added when the page is first generated and it's just the id that is defined via the variable? (ie are they added after the page has finished loading)

Comment: @freedomn-m it returns 0. So, I guess it doesn't find the elements

Comment: @Tasos  Are the `#more-talktime-` elements added dynamically?

Comment: @freedomn-m It is on php code added by Wordpress. So, they should be created before the page loads.

Comment: Can you give an example of the values that are in `{{post.id}}` please?  If you have any special characters eg `.` `,` `>` or spaces, it would affect the second find.

Comment: @freedomn-m those are just wordpress post IDs. For example, those I test are 284 and 285

Comment: Damn, damn, damn... I found the problem. The div element had a typo as you see on the HTML code and instead of `{{post.id}}` it was `{{post-id}}` with a dash. Such a silly mistake. But all of your comments and answers helped me dig more on it and find the issue.

Comment: Change id declaration to "var id = this.attr('id').split('-').pop();"

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work correctly, given the following below. If the checkboxes and divs with the dynamically generated ID's are added to the DOM after the page loads, you may want to utilize the following for the "change" listener..

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('change', '[id^=more-talktime-]', function() {
      var id = this.id.split('-').pop();
      if (this.checked)
        jQuery('#talktime-options-' + id).fadeIn('slow');
      else
        jQuery('#talktime-options-' + id).fadeOut('slow');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.no-display {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="more-talktime-1">Check 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="more-talktime-1" />
<div id="talktime-options-1" class="no-display">Div 1</div>
<label for="more-talktime-2">Check 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="more-talktime-2" />
<div id="talktime-options-2" class="no-display">Div 2</div>
```

Comment: Noted, will be better about it in the future. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: No worries, I apologize if I came off gruff as well, didn't mean to, which is why I deleted my earlier comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

var id = this.*id*.split('-').pop(); to var id = $(this).*attr('id')*.split('-').pop();

Use the .attr() method

You can also use .fadeToggle(), make sure element has display property set to none or block.

Toggle between fading in and fading out

```
$('#talktime-options-' + id).fadeToggle();
$('#talktime-options-' + id).fadeToggle("slow");
$('#talktime-options-' + id).fadeToggle(3000);
```

Comment: In this context, `this` is a DOM node, not a jquery object.  It would have to be `$(this).attr("id")...`.  They both provide the id attribute and OP already stated that they have checked that the id in the var was correct.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('[id^=more-talktime-]').change(function(){
            jQuery('#talktime-options-' + this.id.split('-').pop()).fadeToggle('slow');
        });
    });
 });
```

```css
[id^=talktime-options-]{
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:5px;
border:2px solid #ccc;
float:left;
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="more-talktime-1" />check1
<input type="checkbox" id="more-talktime-2" />check2
<input type="checkbox" id="more-talktime-3" />check3
<hr>
<div  id="talktime-options-1">div1</div>
<div  id="talktime-options-2">div2</div>
<div  id="talktime-options-3">div3</div>
```